# Prestashop:Create a module that override another module?

Tags: module, prestashop

I create a module and this module should also change another module (mailalerts) ,  I temporarily overridden this module into the folder */override/* , but I wish it was all in my module.

Answer (score 0):

If you have

`/modules/mymodule/override/modules/mailalerts/mailalerts.php`,

then this file will be copied to

`/override/modules/mailalerts/mailalerts.php`,

after `mymodule` installation.

Be aware that making a module that overrides other modules is not good practice. You should only use module overrides for your own or your client website and place them directly in the `/override/modules/` folder.